# After Adding RxJava2, application crashes on SocketTimeout

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

Previously in my app, I was making two API calls sequentially: `isCategoryPromoted` and `loadCategoryServices`.

I added RxJava2 into the project so that the requests could be done in parrallel. The code below summarises the implementation:

```
public class ServicesListViewModel{

    public final ObservableBoolean loading = new ObservableBoolean();
    public final ObservableField<String> loadServicesError = new ObservableField<>();

    public void start() {
        loading.set(true);

        final long categoryId = category.getCategoryId();

        final Disposable disposable = Flowable.combineLatest(
                categoriesRepository.isPromotedCategory(categoryId),
                categoriesRepository.loadServices(categoryId),
                (isPromoted, services) -> {

                    //..processing
                }
        ).doOnError(t -> {
            loading.set(false);
            loadServicesError.set(t.getMessage());
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe();
        compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
    }
}
```

,

```
public class ServicesListActivity extends BaseActivity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //inject viewmodel

        setupView();
        bindView();

        viewModel.start();
    }

    private void bindView() {
        loadingObserver = new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int propertyId) {
                if (viewModel.loading.get()) {
                    showProgressDialog();
                } else {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
                binding.btnNext.setEnabled(!viewModel.loading.get());
            }
        };
        viewModel.loading.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(loadingObserver);

        loadServicesErrorObserver = new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int propertyId) {
                showErrorDialog(viewModel.loadServicesError.get(), FINISH_ON_CLICK, false);
            }
        };
        viewModel.loadServicesError.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(loadServicesErrorObserver);

    }
}
```

When the request times out, `loadServicesError` gets set and the code in `showErrorDialog` executes successfully. However just before the error dialog is displayed, the application crashes. The following trace appears in LogCat:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to my.api.com/
>   (port 443) from /192.168.0.10 (port 49969) after 10000000ms:
>   isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
>       at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:271)
>       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:188)
>       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
>       //..truncated..
>       at com.myapp.networking.ApiFactory$2.intercept(ApiFactory.java:166)
>       //..truncated.. Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
>       at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:262)     ... 37 more Force finishing activity ServicesListActivity

The stacktrace includes this line: `com.myapp.networking.ApiFactory$2.intercept(ApiFactory.java:166)`

which is where I intercept the request to include an Authorization token:

```
builder.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        final Request original = chain.request();

        Request.Builder newBuilder = original.newBuilder()
        newBuilder.addHeader("Authorization",apiDelegate.getAccessToken());

        return chain.proceed(request);//line in stack-tract
    }
});
```

My question is: how do I handle this exception?

It seems to be that the system decides that the Activity needs to be finished because the request timed out.

Before adding RxJava2, the same code worked fine so I'm fairly certain the issue is not outside the code posted above.

I've gone through StackOverflow and it seems nearly all the questions suggest simply increasing the session time-out time. I believe this is a hack and there ought to be a perfectly sensible way of solving this issue.

**UPDATE**

**CategoriesRepository.kt**

```
override fun isPromotedCategory(categoryId: Long): Flowable<Boolean> = localSource.isPromotedCategory(categoryId)

override fun loadCategoryServices(categoryId: Long): Flowable<CategoryQuestions>
            = remoteSource.loadCategoryServices(categoryId)
```

**CategoriesLocalDatsSource.kt**

```
override fun isPromotedCategory(categoryId: Long): Flowable<Boolean> {
    return Flowable.create<Boolean>({ subscriber ->
        val isPromotedCategory = dbHelper.promotedCategoryDao.idExists(categoryId)

        subscriber.onNext(isPromotedCategory)
        subscriber.onComplete()
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
}
```

**CategoriesRemoteDataSource.kt**

```
override fun loadCategoryServices(categoryId: Long): Flowable<CategoryServices> {
    return Flowable.create<CategoryServices>({
        service().loadCategoryServices(categoryId)
                .enqueue(object : ApiCallback<CategoryServices>() {
                    override fun success(services: CategoryServices?, response: Response<*>?) {
                        it.onNext(services)
                        it.onComplete()
                    }

                    override fun failure(throwable: Throwable?) {
                        it.onError(throwable)
                    }
                })
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
}
```

Comment: Your stacktrace shows that it timed out after 10,000 seconds, so increasing the timeout won't help, as you say. Therefore, you have an error in either of `isCategoryPromoted()` or `loadCategoryServices()`, neither of which you provide. Since those methods were not used in your previous code, they are likely the culprits.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Those methods were used in the previous version of the code however they used a callback instead of returning a ‘Flowable’. I suspected they might be the cause of the problem however debugging shows that they execute without error. I will include their source code in just a moment

Comment: Your network code is timing out, and you are not sure which network call is doing so? Is the request going out on the wire? What kind of test harness do you have?

Comment: I do know which request is timing out. It is the `loadCategoryServices`. The request does go out on the wire. I do get a `SocketTimeoutException` which is handled in the Flowables `onError`. The only thing I don't understand is why the Android system decides to crash the application. The only exception that links back to my code is in the `intercept()` method

Comment: You don't have an actual error handler in your subscription. While `doOnError()` is fine for reporting errors, it is not the actual handler. Change `subscribe()` to either use an observer, or add the handlers.

Comment: @BobDalgleish: Oh I see where I've gone wrong. Replacing `subscribe()` with `subscribe(Consumer<T> onNext,Consumer<E> onError)`solved the problem. Can you please write an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bob Dalgleish said onError doesn't do what you expect it does.
`subscribe()` has multiple parameters it can take to reflect results, second parameter is what you consider "onError". Remember that exceptions are stream terminal events, that means stream becomes unusable after an exception unless you add error handling operators such as `onErrorReturn()`